# Why does this ruby sequence not work for double digit numbers?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I was creating a program with ruby to organises sequences of numbers. It worked perfectly except when two digit numbers were involved, here is the code:

```
print "Hello participant today we will be rearranging your numbers from smallest to largest, press enter to continue!!"
gets.chomp

print "Please enter your first number"
n1 = gets.chomp

print "Please enter your second number"
n2 = gets.chomp

print "Please enter your third number"
n3 = gets.chomp

print "Please enter your fourth number"
n4 = gets.chomp

print "Please enter your fifth number"
n5 = gets.chomp

a = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]

print "your numbers from smallest to largest are: #{a.sort!}"
gets.chomp

print "thank you for participating, See you next time!!"
```

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers. If you want numbers, do like `n1 = gets.to_i`

Comment: Also, use `a.sort`, not `a.sort!`

Comment: Also JFYI: this example was trivial enough that we could guess what problem you're having. But in the future, if you claim something like "this code doesn't work for this condition", you must elaborate on that: provide what output you __expect__ and what output you are __actually getting__. Also, make sure that the code contains __all necessary input__. In short, you'll need a [mcve]. If you don't provide that, your question is likely to attract downvotes and closevotes (also likely to not get any answers).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am new to this, but i'll take your advice next time I ask a question!!

Comment: Some notes: you do seem to be repeating yourself an awful lot so consider using [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Integer.html#method-i-times); there are two `get.chomps` which serve no purpose; you should use `puts` not `print`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 : Creating an empty array and pushing each element into it is almost never Rubyish.

Comment: @SarimAleem Consider using the [ordinalize gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ordinalize).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Sort array of strings or array of integers

`[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]` is an array of strings, and strings are compared with [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"].sort
#=> ["1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

["12", "11", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"].sort_by(&:to_i)
#=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
```

So you need :

```
print "your numbers from smallest to largest are: #{a.sort_by(&:to_i)}"
```

or just convert your string array to an integer array :

```
a = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5].map(&:to_i)

print "your numbers from smallest to largest are: #{a.sort}"
```

## Refactoring

Here's a shorter way to write your script :

```
puts "Hello participant today we will be rearranging your numbers from smallest to largest, press enter to continue!!"
gets

a = %w(first second third fourth fifth).map do |ordinal|
  puts "Please enter your #{ordinal} number"
  gets.to_i
end

puts "Your numbers from smallest to largest are: #{a.sort}"
gets

puts "Thank you for participating, See you next time!!"
```

Comment: The discrepancy between `String#<=>` and `String#succ` always confuses me: `'9'.succ > '9' #=> false`

Comment: @Stefan `'09'.succ > '09'` ;)

Comment: And it's not just numbers: `'z'.succ > 'z' #=> false` ;-)

Comment: `to_i` does the chomp-ing for you.