# How to sort hash in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a hash

```
x= {
  "1"=>{:name=>"test1", :age=>"1"}, 
  "5"=>{:name=>"test2", :age=>"5"}, 
  "2"=>{:name=>"test3", :age=>"2"}, 
  "4"=>{:name=>"test4", :adn=>"4"}, 
  "3"=>{:name=>"test5", :adn=>"3"}
 }
```

Desired output

```
x= {
  "1"=>{:name=>"test1", :age=>"1"}, 
  "2"=>{:name=>"test3", :age=>"2"}, 
  "3"=>{:name=>"test5", :age=>"3"}, 
  "4"=>{:name=>"test4", :adn=>"4"}, 
  "5"=>{:name=>"test2", :adn=>"5"}
 }
```

What I have so far, I tried doing x.sort.flatten and i got

```
[
  "1", {:name=>"test1", :age=>"1"}, 
  "2", {:name=>"test3", :age=>"2"}, 
  "3", {:name=>"test5", :adn=>"3"}, 
  "4", {:name=>"test4", :adn=>"4"}, 
  "5", {:name=>"test2", :age=>"5"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some other ways of doing that.

```
x.keys.sort_by(&:to_i).each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = x[k] }
  #=> {"1"=>{:name=>"test1", :age=>"1"},
  #    "2"=>{:name=>"test3", :age=>"2"},
  #    "3"=>{:name=>"test5", :adn=>"3"},
  #    "4"=>{:name=>"test4", :adn=>"4"},
  #    "5"=>{:name=>"test2", :age=>"5"}}
```

or

```
k = x.keys.sort_by(&:to_i)
k.zip(x.values_at(*k)).to_h
```

and if `x` is to be modified,

```
x.keys.sort_by(&:to_i).each { |k| x[k] = x.delete(k) }
x
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to sort a hash directly. Converting to a sorted array and back again :

```
x.sort_by{ |key,_| key.to_i }.to_h
```

It outputs :

```
=> {"1"=>{:name=>"test1", :age=>"1"},
 "2"=>{:name=>"test3", :age=>"2"},
 "3"=>{:name=>"test5", :adn=>"3"},
 "4"=>{:name=>"test4", :adn=>"4"},
 "5"=>{:name=>"test2", :age=>"5"}}
```

If you want to sort by age :

```
x.sort_by{|k,v| v[:age].to_i}.to_h
```

If you want to sort by age or adn (in case it wasn't a typo) :

```
x.sort_by{|k,v| ( v[:age] || v[:adn] ).to_i}.to_h
```

Comment: Pinching your idea from another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41261105/5101493) you posted today: `x.sort_by { |k,_| k.to_i }` would be better, no?

Comment: I didn't notice that the key was also a string. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You almost do it, just replace `flatten` with `to_h`

```
x.sort.to_h
# => {"1"=>{:name=>"test1", :age=>"1"}, "2"=>{:name=>"test3", :age=>"2"}, "3"=>{:name=>"test5", :adn=>"3"}, "4"=>{:name=>"test4", :adn=>"4"}, "5"=>{:name=>"test2", :age=>"5"}}
```

Works in ruby 2.1.8

Comment: Note that keys are strings and won't be sorted as integers